# How to prevent a CSS animation from going back to its original position?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So, my CSS moves a div to -40px after 3 seconds. After doing so, the div is then moved back to its original position. Here is the code:

```
#jsAlert {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    animation:mymove 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;

    /*Safari and Chrome*/
    -webkit-animation: mymove 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: -40px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /*Safari and Chrome*/
{
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: -40px;}
}
```

How would I prevent the div from returning to its original position?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) with a value set to [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#Values)

From Mozilla Developer Network:

> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe
>   encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on
>   the value of `animation-direction` and `animation-iteration-count`

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h3RYh/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

i would not recommend using @keyframes for this simple animation.

this article may help you

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/css3_animations_vs_transitions.htm

> Conclusion There you have it - a candid look at what makes transitions
>   and animations similar yet so very different. My general approach for
>   determining when to use which goes like this:
>
> If what I want requires the flexibility provided by having multiple
>   keyframes and easy looping, then I go with an animation. If I am
>   looking for a simple from/to animation, I go with a transition. If I
>   want to manipulate the property values that I wish to animate using
>   JavaScript, I go with a transition.

cause performance is a valuable thing .

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets here and is using an `<animate>` tag: `fill="freeze"` is the solution.